# show just the street address in google.maps.event.addListener()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have written a small function that will get the user address using the `google.maps.event.addListener()`. Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subash1232/K6SWN/1/).

Everything is exactly what I want, apart from when the user finishes typing and focus out from the `street` field, I just want the street address in the `input`.

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: now]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

Thanks already for help. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a short delay to apply streetAddress

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#address').val(streetAddress);},50);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solution works great to autocomplete individual address fields. Here's an implementation with options to bias the results, however I'm having problems using bounds to bias the results of the autocomplete field. Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmhGS/22/).

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.89028890,-117.5617340),
    new google.maps.LatLng(33.7706850,-117.6639850)
);

var updateAddress = {
    autocomplete: new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], { 
        bounds: defaultBounds,
        types: ['geocode'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    }),            
    event: function(){
        var self = this;    
        google.maps.event.addListener(self.autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = self.autocomplete.getPlace(),
                address = place.address_components,
                streetAddress = '',
                suburb = '',
                state = '',
                zip = '',
                country = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
                var addressType = address[i].types[0];

                if (addressType == 'subpremise') {
                    streetAddress += address[i].long_name + '/';
                }
                if (addressType == 'street_number') {
                    streetAddress += address[i].long_name + ' ';
                }
                if (address[i].types[0] == 'route') {
                    streetAddress += address[i].long_name;
                }
                if (addressType == 'locality') {
                    suburb = address[i].long_name;
                }
                if (addressType == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                    state = address[i].long_name;
                }
                if (addressType == 'postal_code') {
                    zip = address[i].long_name;
                }
                if (addressType == 'country') {
                    country = address[i].long_name;
                }
            }

            // update the textboxes
            setTimeout(function(){$('#address').val(streetAddress);},50);
            $('#suburb').val(suburb);
            $('#state').val(state);
            $('#zip').val(zip);
        });

    }
};

updateAddress.event();
```