# Google Places Autocomplete - modifying results

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I have some standard google places autocomplete code that works fine. I want to modify the result when the user selects an address from the list.

For example one of the results is

'45 Alexandra Road Holiday Flats, Alexandra Road, Southport, United Kingdom'

When the user selectes it from the list I would like the following value to appear in the text box

'45 Alexandra Road Holiday Flats, Alexandra Road, Southport, PR4 5JD'

ie, I want the post/zip code to be inserted and the United Kingdom to be removed.

I can do this in the place_changed event, the post/zip code is available and I can do some string manipulation and get the result I want.

However when I assign it to the txtBox at the end of the 'place_changed' function, something then changes it back to the original selected value without the post/zip code. This is something that has changed recently as my code used to work. The assignment/binding of the value to the txtBox happens after the place_changed event now it would seem.

```
var autoCompleteObject = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(txtBox[0], GooglePlacesOptions);
// Autocomplete Listener
google.maps.event.addListener(autoCompleteObject, 'place_changed', function () {

    var place = autoCompleteObject.getPlace();

    txtBox.val('45 Alexandra Road Holiday Flats, Alexandra Road, Southport, PR4 5JD');

});
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I have decided not to use the AutoComplete functionality and use the PlacesService.textSearch() instead.

Quite easy and you have more control over results and how they are displayed etc..

So the question still remains but my head is less sore :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I found the answer to the following helpful as an effective workaround:
[show just the street address in google.maps.event.addListener()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524258/show-just-the-street-address-in-google-maps-event-addlistener)