# Google Place Autocomplete affecting key down behaviour in input

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RwcGQxznsC4rqoMqaMo3?p=preview) there is an input with Google Place Autocomplete attached.

When it has focus and the tab key is used the $scope.data.keyDown function is called but the text of the input is not updated. Without the attachment the input text is changed to "hello". You can see this by simply commenting out the attachment line

```
  // var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(placeAutoCompleteInput, {types: ['(cities)']});
```

Why does Autocomplete have this effect and is there a way round it?

JS

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $element) {
  $scope.data = {};

  var placeAutoCompleteInput = $element[0].querySelector('#place');
  var autoComplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(placeAutoCompleteInput, {types: ['(cities)']});

  $scope.data.keyDown = function($event) {
    if ($event.keyCode == 9) { // Tab key
        $scope.data.text = "hello";
    }
  }
});
```

Markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input id="place" ng-model="data.text" ng-keydown="data.keyDown($event)">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working [plnkr solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/0No3wMwwaKKTKNOUmpk6?p=preview) for you

```
$scope.data.keyDown = function($event) {
    console.log("keyDown", $event);
    if ($event.keyCode == 9) { // Tab key

        $scope.data.text = "hello";

        //fix
        placeAutoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
          placeAutoCompleteInput.value = $scope.data.text;
        });

    }
  };
```

Follow this [link to stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925008/change-the-value-in-textbox-of-a-google-map-autocomplete) and read Nicholas Ryan Bowers answer for more insight.

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on, let me play around with your plunker.

Comment: Looks good to me. Thanks for the link in the answer and for adding that extra tag to the question.

Comment: It will, just remove brackets () --> placeAutoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', test);